# Cannot resolve keyword u'blanks' into field. Choices are: id, name, sort_order

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have this question posted many times but couldn't find the solution to my problem.

Below, my code is working fine in Django 1.6.3 but after updating to 1.9.6 it's not working, although I have updated all dependencies and have made all database migrations.

I am getting said error at:

```
for color_group in blank.color_groups.all():
```

point in view.py

Below is my code

Model.py

```
class ColorGroup(models.Model):
    """Categorization for Colors"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sort_order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sort_order']
        app_label='portal'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Blank(models.Model):
    """
    A particular instance of a printable item, such as the Black Men's 
    American Apparel 50/50 t-shirt.
    """
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blank_images", blank=True, validators=[validate_file_extension])
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    style = models.ForeignKey(BlankStyle)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Featured?", default=False)
    color_groups = models.ManyToManyField(ColorGroup, related_name='blanks')

    def as_hash(self):
         image_url = ""
         if self.image:
             image_url = self.image.url

        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'color': self.color,
            'style_code': self.style.code,
            'style': self.style.as_hash(),
            'image_url': image_url,
            'sizes': [bs.as_hash() for bs in self.sizes.all()]
         }

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        if self.image:
            return self.image.url
        return None

    @property
    def public_thumbnail_url(self):
        from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
        if self.image:
            im = get_thumbnail(self.image, '58x58', crop='center',quality=99)
            return im.url
        return None

    @property
    def public_medium_url(self):
        from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
        if self.image:
            im = get_thumbnail(self.image, '382x456',quality=99)
            return im.url
        return None

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.style.code + ": " + self.color


    class Meta:
        app_label = 'portal'
```

and view.py

```
def order_new_json_data(request,all=False):
    # Brands
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    json_brands = serializers.serialize("json", brands)

    # Blanks
    blanks = Blank.objects.prefetch_related('style').filter(is_featured=True).order_by('style__id')

    # custom output
    blank_list = []
    for blank in blanks.all():
        color_groups = []
        for color_group in blank.color_groups.all():
            color_groups.append(color_group.pk)
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 149. response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 147. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view 149. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/clockwise/public/orders/views.py" in order_new_json_data 356. for color_group in blank.color_groups.all():
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in all 223. return self.get_queryset()
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in get_queryset 792. return qs._next_is_sticky().filter(**self.core_filters)
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter 790. return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude 808. clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q 1243. clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q 1269. allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter 1149. lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in solve_lookup_type 1035. _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
File "/home/muhammad/Desktop/ClockwiseLatest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path 1330. "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /orders/new/json_data/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword u'blanks' into field. Choices are: id, name, sort_order
```

Comment: What error are you getting? can you please put the stack trace in your question.

Comment: Hi rrao, thank you for your interest. please see the traceback that i have posted into my question.

Comment: What if you change the `related_name='blanks'` ?

Comment: i did try but no luck.

Comment: Even i tried after removing **related_name='blanks'.**

Comment: Result after changing **related_name**

FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'blanks_r' into field. Choices are: id, name, sort_order

Comment: Point `makemigrations` to your appname: `makemigrations appname`

Comment: Thanks @MosesKoledoye for your interest but your answer is not help full for me.